# What does "be rounded in" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "be rounded in" mean in this context?

> All things are in their places in this little world, because all is natural and free, just as "there is room for everything out of doors." Yet **all is rounded in by natural harmony**, which will always arise where Truth and Love are sought in the light of Freedom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Round" as a verb has the meaning "to encircle or surround" [dictionary sense 51](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/round). There is also phrasal verb "round up" meaning to gather animals (etc) into a herd. I think this is the sense suggested by the context.

The meaning I understand is "All things are surrounded and encirled by natural harmony (which therefore ensures that all things are in their places)" The exact phrase "round in" is not common, and is not listed in the dictionaries I checked.